# Why is the link from a featured snippet not behaving like one from a regular search result?

Tags: google-search, amp

When I run the search "rick ross net worth" the featured snippet is an article from theexchange.africa. When I open the link on mobile, there are no ads shown.

If instead I search "in: theexchange.africa rick ross net worth", the top result is still the same article but not as a featured snippet. When I open on it on mobile, there are ads showing.

My question is: Why would the mobile ads only show in the second scenario and not the first despite both linking to the same article?

**Further Clarification**:

I have set up Auto AMP Ads for theexchange.africa. If I visit an article directly from it's link (eg. https://theexchange.africa/africa-billionaires/michiel-le-roux/) the ads show as expected.

Now since site visitors are more likely to get to the articles from a Google search, I went ahead and did the search described above. For some reason, if the article is accessed from a regular search result, the ads show up, but if accessed from a featured snippet then the ads don't show.

Could it have something to do with the content being served from https://theexchange-africa.cdn.ampproject.org?

Comment: I voted to close this because it appears to be about how Google works and not about running your own website.  If this is indeed about your own website, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have updated the question. Hopefully it's clearer now.